# Selecting multiple integer values

Tags: multi-selection

I have a field called link which is an integer and i choose it from a combo box.
In my former case, every link has only one destination. So when sending a message, i only choose the link then click send button.

Now the case is that each link contains multiple destinations. Each message can now be sent to many destinations.

Normally the destinations for a link are fixed ( a list of integers). But there are some exceptions. So i rarely send the message to a destination(integer) not showed in the list.

To summarize, i need a component that i can enter an integer, select multiple integers. If it contains a list it should be opened as required like a combobox. Also there can be a better way combining the link and the destination in one field.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a roll-your-own solution. To the user it looks like a drop-down; he selects it and there is a place to enter text as well as the drop-down.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWYiKo.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>